# Aggressive cat towards my wife but is super affectionate with me

Tags: cats, aggression

We have a 5 year old Egyptian Mau rescued from the streets.
She has a weird habit whenever she sees my wife laying in bed with the phone in her hand she would analyze the situation in how to charge at my wife and bite her hand(quite hard) usually there is blood.

I find this attitude very weird as she is the one who feeds her, clean her litter, plays with her, buys her food and toys, however the cat is very affectionate towards me. We both work from home so, she would wait next to me like a well trained dog until I finish what work I have to do, she would come and give me kisses and try to “get into my soul”. She has like a completely different approach between us. I am not sure what to think of this and what to do.

Anybody having an idea of what it might be happening in her head…
Thank you!

Comment: Have you ever tried doing the same as your wife (lie in bed with the phone) to see if the cat reacts the same way?

Comment: Is your wife with the cat from the beginning for all those 5 years, or was the cat first with you and then after some time you met your wife and you and your cat "started sharing the space with your wife"?

Comment: Is your wife's phone-volume set on high?  Some kitties may react negatively to sounds that they perceive to be very loud.

Answer (score 3):

Hah, who knows what goes on in cats' heads. But I think you're right to try to suss out what your cat is hoping to "accomplish" and then work to deter the behavior through positive reinforcements, distraction, etc. (As opposed to punishment-based deterring like hitting or yelling. Not great for many reasons but cats are pretty famous for not responding well to this and in fact might amp up their aggressive-seeming behaviors.)

It seems like this could be coming from a place of aggression or a place of playfulness. Does it appear your cat is attacking your wife out of aggression? Are her ears back, fur standing on end, any growling or other vocalizations? Does she keep coming back for more (play) or is it a one time pounce/bite and then she goes to hide (aggression)?

It could be her attacks are actually coming out of a desire to play but she is playing too roughly. Does she do any other play-type behaviors besides biting? I have a cat who bites in play sometimes but I can tell she's not intending to cause me harm specifically because she will also kick and pounce and dart around, just as she does when she's playing with a mouse toy.

Regardless of what is motivating your cat, cat bites can be a major health risk and I'm sure are upsetting for you and your wife so I think it's smart to try to deal with this. If it seems this is less from aggression but is more an inappropriate bid for attention, I wonder if you and your wife could play with your cat before getting into bed with the phone with the hopes of tiring her out. And anytime she attacks your wife the cat is firmly told "no!" and then put out of the room. This might reinforce to your cat that this method of 'play' isn't going to get her the outcome she's hoping for. And hopefully positively engaging her through play will satisfy the need she is having.  (A loud "OW!" from me and then me removing my hand is enough to reset the situation with my own cat.)

If it's coming from aggression (which is often animals expressing fear) I wonder if your wife doubling down on positive associations could help. She's already clearly doing so much to care for your cat, but maybe really going over the top by having a daily treat session (perhaps treats before getting into bed with the phone.) And have your wife be the ONLY person your cat can get treats from. This might help the cat re-establish a positive bond with your wife.

Ultimately though cats are weird in how they engage with one of their humans over the others and it's often logic defying! Focusing on deterring the biting feels like the main concern.

Answer (score 0):

That seems more like play behaviour to me.

Could it be that your cat just wants some more play time?

If you can, try to figure out what precipitates the attack.

And lastly, I've never heard of cats doing this, but there is some anecdotal evidence of dogs "worrying" on cancerous growths in their humans. [1] [2] [3] so they would be growling or reacting at certain body parts and later on it would come to light that they have a growth or cancer at that point.

Don't mean to scare you, and as I said never heard this with cats.

[1] https://www.health.com/condition/ovarian-cancer/dog-detects-owners-cancer-before-doctors
[2]https://news.cancerresearchuk.org/2009/02/03/can-dogs-detect-the-smell-of-cancer/
[3]https://wagwalking.com/sense/can-a-dog-tell-if-you-have-cancer

Comment: Please add some source for the facts you state. For example for the cancer attacking part.

Comment: Thanks Allerleirauth

Answer (score 0):

I agree it is play behavior. Both you and your wife must NOT use your hands or arms when playing with the cat. It is confusing to them if they are permitted to bite & scratch hands and arms at one time but not another. Find other ways to exercise the cat.